# What are these cycles in orbital eccentricity called?

Tags: astrophysics

I have created a simulator for planetary systems. When I run it with our own solar system and plot the eccentricity, aphelion and perihelion of the orbit of Earth i get these cycles.

[image]

Do these cycles depend on errors in the simulation or are they a they a real thing? If they are real what are they called and where can I read about them?

Comment: If they are accurate (rather than features of a problem with your simulations), then taken together with some other factors (precession of the equinoxes...) they go by the collective name [Milankovitch cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles). That article might break out the individual contributions for you, but I am officially out of my depth.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity#Examples suggests 
your values for Earth's long-term eccentricity are a bit high: "Over 
hundreds of thousands of years, the eccentricity of the Earth's orbit 
varies from nearly 0.0034 to almost 0.058". As the article @dmckee 
links notes, VSOP theory can give you a fairly good idea of Earth's 
eccentricity, perihelion and aphelion: 
http://www.caglow.com/info/compute/vsop87